# Hive over Tez via Hive JDBC - Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using Hortonworks Hadoop HDP-2.3.2.0-2950
Hive over Tez engine

Below 2 queries are from Java code.

- `select * from ascii` -- works well
- `select count(*) from ascii or select count(1) from ascii` -- fails with error out

My code:

```
package com.hadoop.hive;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 * 
 * @author hdpadmin
 *
 */
public class HiveReadJDBCMain {
        private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws SQLException
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
                Connection con = null;
                PreparedStatement pst = null;
                ResultSet  res = null;

                try {

                        // Load Hive Driver Clazz
                        Class.forName(driverName);
                        // No username and password required.(running in a local machine)
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/labs");
                        //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/labs", "<Username>", "<Password>");
                        String tableName = "ascii";
                        // select * query
                        String sql = "select * from " + tableName;
                        System.out.println("Select Query Running: " + sql);
                        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        res = pst.executeQuery();
                        while (res.next()) {
                                System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
                        }
                        pst.close();
                        res.close();

                        // regular hive query
                        sql = "select count(*) from " + tableName;
                        System.out.println("Count Query Running: " + sql);
                        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        res = pst.executeQuery();
                        while (res.next()) {
                                System.out.println(res.getString(1));
                        }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(1);
                } finally {
                        res.close();
                        pst.close();
                        con.close();
                }
        }
}

Error
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:282)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:378)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeQuery(HivePreparedStatement.java:109)
        at com.hadoop.hive.HiveReadJDBCMain.main(HiveReadJDBCMain.java:48)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes i have fixed by passing the below connection objects with my user name
Thanks.... :)

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/labs", "hdpadmin","");
```

Comment: did adding username fixed your error? I am stuck with same error. Tag me if you find solution.and yes I have added username and still getting error

Answer (score 2):

i also fixed by passing username in connection string . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In case your using the AWS Hive JDBC to talk with a default EMR cluster the following setup in Intellij worked for me[image]

The trick was using user `hadoop`